# Send JSON from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: json

I use [Request solution](https://github.com/ded/reqwest) for ajax-request, but I get an error:

> reqwest.min.js:6 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://...' was loaded
>   over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://...'. This request has been blocked; the content must be
>   served over HTTPS.

Server-side code (i'm using wordpress plugin for this):

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wpse144893_search', 'wpse144893_search_data'); // allow logged out users
add_action('wp_ajax_wpse144893_search', 'wpse144893_search_data'); // allow logged in users

function wpse144893_search_data(){
header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

    $errors = array();
    $data = array(
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => '',
        'result' => array()
    );

    if(!isset($_REQUEST['term']) || empty($_REQUEST['term']))
        $errors[] = 'No search term given!';


    if(!isset($_REQUEST['limit']) || empty($_REQUEST['limit']))
        $limit = 10;
    else
        $limit = (int) $_REQUEST['limit'];

    if(empty($errors)){

        $term = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['term']);

        // setup query data
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => $limit,
            's' => $term
        );

        $query = new WP_Query($args); // run query

        $results = array();
        if($query->have_posts()): while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
            $post_item = array(
                'title' => get_the_title(),
                'excerpt' => get_the_excerpt(),
                'permalink' => get_permalink()
            );
            $results[] = $post_item;
        endwhile;
            $data['status'] = 'success';
            $data['message'] = 'Results found!';
            $data['result'] = $results;
        else:
            $errors[] = 'No post found!';
            $data['message'] = $errors;
        endif;
    }

    echo json_encode($data); // print json

    die(); // kill the script
}
```

Client-side code (request plugin):

```
    reqwest({
    url: 'http://...'
  , type: 'json'
  , method: 'get'
  , crossOrigin: true
  , withCredentials: true
  , error: function (err) { alert('1'); }
  , success: function (resp) {
     alert('2');
    }
})
```

I tried use this `header('Content-type: application/json');header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` (see in server code above) but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: What is unclear about "the content must be served over HTTPS"?

Comment: So there is no way to make it work without the transfer of the second server to https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved by moving second server to HTTPS...